# Input range for TPA311x

Tags: amplifier, datasheet, input

I'm reading through the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa3118d2.pdf) of the TPA311x family.
I'm looking for the input range for pins INPR and INPL but I cannot find this information. I see the absolute maximum ratings, but it's not what I need. I'm interested in the maximum recommended input range for the audio signal.

I also measure an offset of about 2.90V on those pins, but in the ds I can't find this value neither.

If it's not declared, is it safe to use all the available swing, i.e. 2.90V ±2.90V? It means the input signal might swing from 0.00V to 5.80V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also measure an offset of about 2.90V on those pins, but in the ds I
>   can't find this value neither.

The DS states the pins are biased at 3 volts (page 2).

> I'm looking for the input range for pins INPR and INPL but I cannot
>   find this information.

You take the gain value (programmed at power up) and reverse back from the preferred maximum peak-to-peak output voltage (supply dependent and dictated by your preferred worst case distortion levels) to get the required peak-to-peak input signal.

Comment: Ok, it's hidden in the description of the pins at page 4, indeed. I was looking in the specification tables. Got the right procedure to calculate the input range. Thanks.