# Inputs to TDA7498E Audio Amplifier

Tags: amplifier, audio, class-d

I am planning to use TDA7498E in one of my projects and was going through the datasheet of the same and got confused at one point. In the absolute maximum ratings, it is written that the INPA, INNA, INPB, INNB have the maximum input ratings of -0.3V to +4V.

The thing which got me confused is that since the analog audio signal is more or less like a sine wave with equal peaks both in positive and negative, then how are we supposed to provide the input to the TDA7498E?

Any audio source will at one point give an audio signal greater than -0.3V (In absolute terms).
Please let me know if I am thinking in the wrong direction.

[Absolute Ratings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6Pox.png)

[Datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tda7498e.pdf)

Comment: Another thing that confuses me is that why have rated digital signals along with Analog signals. Two are completely different domains...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audio is fed in differentially.

Page 7 of the datasheet has an example schematic that shows how it is done.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part but I intend to use this as single-ended Input.

Comment: Yes, the schematic explains how you connect a single ended source into the chip which has differential inputs.

Comment: Supposing that my single-ended signal is a sine wave of 1Khz, 1Vp-p. How should I input this to TDA7498E? Should I bias it to a DC offset voltage? Because the negative half of the wave will kill the IC.

Comment: Would you please actually look at the datasheet schematics to see how it is done.

Comment: I got that part completely okay. To connect negative input to the GND and provide the signal on the positive input.
But what I am asking is regarding the voltage level. Maybe I am not able to explain properly

Comment: The important point is the voltage level that these pins can handle. They are not able to handle more than -0.3V reference to ground. Audio signal being on both side of the graph will kill it.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you don't understand, what is unclear and what kind of answer you want. But, if you use the schematics in the datasheet, you can feed in any single ended audio you want, including your sine wave of 1 kHz of 1Vpp. Maybe you don't see that the signal path is capacitively coupled?

Comment: The input cannot go beyond -0.3V. Now if we give 1Vp-p, won't the -1V kill the input opamp as per the datasheet?
Capacitively coupled saves from the DC, but ac still passes and -1V will still reach the input pin.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/458256/input-range-for-tpa311x?rq=1


My question is more or less similar, with the difference that TDA7498 does not provide a reference voltage.

Comment: OK, so why do you think TDA7498E does not provide a DC bias? Where does it say that it doesn't? If they provide the evaluation board schematics and say it can be connected to an audio source such as a DVD player or test equipment priced more than a new car, it would not make sense the chip just blows up.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for clearing this. I was thinking the wrong direction earlier.